# conversion array into array by jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have following json data . I want to transform following data by jolt nifi processor into result data

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "source": "Environment Sensors",
      "alert_count": "2",
      "category": "envs",
      "alert_array": {
        "alerts": [
          {
            "name": "neeraj",
            "id": "123"
          },
          {
            "name": "arun",
            "id": "897"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

result data

```json
{
  "alert": "2",
  "subcategory": "envs",
  "alert_array": [
    {
      "category": "Environment Sensors",
      "newName": "neeraj",
      "newID": "123"
    },
    {
      "category": "Environment Sensors",
      "newName": "arun",
      "newID": "897"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here value of **category** is the value of **source**

Comment: sir I have created the spac but i am not able to convert source data into categary

Comment: yes ofcourse your answer help and with the help of your help I have created my spac but now i have come with other problem and in this problem I am not able to convert source data into categary .

Comment: Please help to resolve this issue

Comment: Soory for late response . Actually i was not using stack over flow before and i was not aware bout this feature of stackoverflow

Comment: No problem :) , yes you're newly contributing ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "alert_count": "alert",
          "category": "sub&",
          "alert_array": {
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "@(3,category)": "&3[&1].category",
                "name": "&3[&1].newName",
                "id": "&3[&1].newID"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

first reach the elements of the innermost object, and determine the value of the category element by going 3 levels up along with the others which are alreay located there.

Comment: you're welcome @Neeraj , good luck!